# Is there any page specific property to replace session["user_id"]

Tags: asp.net

In my page i have used `Session["user_id"]` to know the status of user. Is there any page specific property to replace `Session["user_id"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session` is the best place to store user id!

---

You can wrap user id keeping using next extension method:

as far as `Page.User` returns `IPrincipal` then:

```
public static string UserId (this IPrincipal user)
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.State["user_id"];
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.State["user_id"] = value;
    }
}
```

Usage (inside a web page);

```
this.Request.User.UserId; // get, set
```

Comment: @Shalni: How can I help you?:)

Comment: May you give SKYPE id? Please...    So that i can ask question from you on your id...

Comment: @Shalni: Write me a letter to abatishchev at gmail dot com

Answer (score -1):

you can use a query string to store the user id instead of a session, moving it along from page to page.

another option is to use a viewstate, but this is limited per page and does not move along to other pages

Comment: Well secured if used only by `Server.Transfer()`, and not - if `Response.Redirect()`, i.e. without query string stripping